# Is it possible to export Ab Initio graph as image?

Tags: ab-initio

Am doing migration project, migration of Ab Initio graph to java.
Is it possible to export Ab Initio graph as image so that its helpful to refer specially when Ab initio IDE is not available. So far am doing print screen but as graphs go bigger and complex the print screen is not so helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could "print" the graph and then select the output as a .PDF file.
You will not have a picture this way, however you'll have a graph in a a file that has fully scalable fonts which makes sense if your graphs tend to get bigger.